# How to define a group and tell if it's Abelian

Tags: matrices, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am taking an into to math in data science class. The issue is that it's been 15 years since my last math class and my abstract evaluation skills are rusty. The problem is as follows:

Consider the set $\mathscr{G}$ of 3x3 matrices defined as follows:

$$ \mathscr{G} = \Bigg\{\Bigg[\begin{matrix}1&x&z\\
0&1&y\\
0&0&1\end{matrix} \Bigg] \in \mathbb{R}^{3x3} \Bigg| x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} \Bigg\}$$

We define $\cdot$ as the standard matrix multiplication.

Is $(\mathscr{G}, \cdot)$ a group? If so, is it Abelian?

I guess I just mainly don't understand what the question is asking at the end. The matrix by itself cannot be a group. So is the second part saying "This given matrix, with another 3x3 matrix that is in the realm of real numbers?"

If so, when looking at the criteria for Abelian groups: Binary operation on G, Associativity, Identity Element, Inverses, and Commutativity:

I know that multiplying this 3x3 matrix by another 3x3 matrix will give the proper shape, but how do I demonstrate a binary operation if I can't know that x,y or z will be 0?

I know that matrix multiplication is associative.

Then I get very confused because the Identity element for a 3x3 matrix would mean x.y,z are all equal to zero, right?

At this point, my brain is hurting and I can't understand how to get the inverse of the matrix. A 2x2 is simple, but I keep getting different answers every time I try with this 3x3 matrix. I think this is just a simple math error, but I am not sure.

So then with commutativity, I don't ever find a solution where a 3x3 matrix is commutative with the format of the given matrix.

So am I correct that at least the group isn't Ablian? How do I find out if it's a group?

Comment: Are you confused as to what $\mathscr{G} $ actually is, first and foremost?

Comment: I think you should show the product of any two elements of $\mathcal G$ is in $\mathcal G$ (closure). Like you, I think you can carry over associativity from all square matrices. The multiplicative identity is the same as for all square matrices.  You should find the multiplicative inverse of a general element of $\mathcal G$.  If all those are satisfied, you have a group.  The question of being Abelian may be answerable from the closure calculation: either show it it true in general or show a single counter-example

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal G$ is a set of matrices, and not a single matrix.

Does this set of matrices, together with with the operation of matrix multiplication form a group?

Is it closed?  Is it associative? Is there an identity matrix? Does every matrix in $\mathcal G$ have an inverse in $\mathcal G$?

Associativity and the identity matrix are inherited with the operation, so we don't really need to test those.  Matrix mulitplication is generally not commutative, but in special cases, it is.

For closure, pick two generic matrices in the set, multiply them together and what do you get?

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&x_1&y_1\\0&1&z_1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&x_2&y_2\\0&1&z_2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&x_1 + x_2&y_1 + y_2 + x_1z_2\\0&1&z_1 +z_2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Is it in $\mathcal G$?  If we can find an inverse, is that in $\mathcal G$?

Does it look like this is one of those cases where matrix multiplication commutes?

Comment: Thanks! This helped!